# Google Visualization getDataTable is not a function (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am drawing a Google timeline chart from data queried from multiple Google Sheets. The code works fine, but only sometimes. If I keep refreshing the page sometimes the table draws, sometimes not. The error I get when the table doesn't draw is 'Error handling Query strict JSON response: TypeError: a.getDataTable is not a function'. My relevant code is below. How do I handle this?

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <!--Load the AJAX API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['timeline']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
            
          var dataA = "";
          var dataB = "";
          var dataC = "";
          var dataD = "";
          var dataE = "";
          var dataF = "";
          var dataG = "";
          var dataH = "";
            
            function initialize() {
                  var opts = {sendMethod: 'auto'};
                  var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT J, K, C, E, F WHERE I=1');
                
                  var queryA = new google.visualization.Query(
                      'xxx=' + queryString);
                  
                  var queryB = new google.visualization.Query(
                      'xxx' + queryString);
                
                  var queryC = new google.visualization.Query(
                      'xxx' + queryString);
                
                  var queryD = new google.visualization.Query(
                      'xxx' + queryString);
                
                  var queryE = new google.visualization.Query(
                      'xxx' + queryString);
                
                  var queryF = new google.visualization.Query(
                      'xxx' + queryString);
                
                  var queryG = new google.visualization.Query(
                      'xxx' + queryString);
                
                  var queryH = new google.visualization.Query(
                      'xxx' + queryString);
                
                queryA.send(handleQueryResponse);
                
                queryA.send(getDataA);
                queryB.send(getDataB);
                queryC.send(getDataC);
                queryD.send(getDataD);
                queryE.send(getDataE);
                queryF.send(getDataF);
                queryG.send(getDataG);
                queryH.send(getDataH);
            }
    
            function handleQueryResponse(response) {
                  if (response.isError()) {
                    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                    return;
                  }
            }
            
            function getDataA(response){ dataA = response; }
            function getDataB(response){ dataB = response; }
            function getDataC(response){ dataC = response; }
            function getDataD(response){ dataD = response; }
            function getDataE(response){ dataE = response; }
            function getDataF(response){ dataF = response; }
            function getDataG(response){ dataG = response; }
            
            function getDataH(response){
                  dataH = response;
                  drawThatChart();
            }
            
            function drawThatChart(){
                  drawChart(dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD, dataE, dataF, dataG, dataH);
            }
    
            
    function drawChart(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) {
        
      var container = document.getElementById('point');
      var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
      var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      var x = "";
      var y = "";
      var theData = "";
      var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: 'yyyy, M, d' });
        
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'dummy bar label' });
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' });
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        
      var countRowA = a.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
      var countColumnA = a.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
        
      var countRowB = b.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
      var countColumnB = b.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
        
      var countRowC = c.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
      var countColumnC = c.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
        
      var countRowD = d.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
      var countColumnD = d.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
        
      var countRowE = e.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
      var countColumnE = e.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
        
      var countRowF = f.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
      var countColumnF = f.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
        
      var countRowG = g.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
      var countColumnG = g.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
        
      var countRowH = h.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
      var countColumnH = h.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
        
     formatDate.format(a.getDataTable(), 3);
     formatDate.format(a.getDataTable(), 4);
        
     formatDate.format(b.getDataTable(), 3);
     formatDate.format(b.getDataTable(), 4);
        
     formatDate.format(c.getDataTable(), 3);
     formatDate.format(c.getDataTable(), 4);
        
     formatDate.format(d.getDataTable(), 3);
     formatDate.format(d.getDataTable(), 4);
        
     formatDate.format(e.getDataTable(), 3);
     formatDate.format(e.getDataTable(), 4);
        
     formatDate.format(f.getDataTable(), 3);
     formatDate.format(f.getDataTable(), 4);
        
     formatDate.format(g.getDataTable(), 3);
     formatDate.format(g.getDataTable(), 4);
        
     formatDate.format(h.getDataTable(), 3);
     formatDate.format(h.getDataTable(), 4);
        
     dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'PROJECTS', null, '<div class="ggl-tooltip" style="display: none;"></div>', new Date(2021, 0, 1), new Date(2021, 11, 31) ]
     ]);
        
        var $project = '';
        var $toolTip = '';
        var $dteStrt = '';
        var $dteStrtSplt = '';
        var $yrS = '';
        var $moS = '';
        var $daS = '';
        var $dTotal = "";
        var $day = '';
        var $dteEnd = '';
        var $dteEndSplt = '';
        var $yrE = '';
        var $moE = '';
        var $daE = '';
        
      for(var i = 0; i < countRowA; i++) {
          for(var ii = 0; ii < countColumnA; ii++) {
              if (ii == 0) {
                    $project = a.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
                    $dteStrt = a.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 3);
                    $dteStrtSplt = $dteStrt.split(",");
                    $yrS = $dteStrtSplt[0];
                    $moS = $dteStrtSplt[1] - 1;
                    $daS = $dteStrtSplt[2];
                    if ($moS == 0) { $toolMonth = "Jan"; }
                    if ($moS == 1) { $toolMonth = "Feb"; }
                    if ($moS == 2) { $toolMonth = "Mar"; }
                    if ($moS == 3) { $toolMonth = "Apr"; }
                    if ($moS == 4) { $toolMonth = "May"; }
                    if ($moS == 5) { $toolMonth = "Jun"; }
                    if ($moS == 6) { $toolMonth = "Jul"; }
                    if ($moS == 7) { $toolMonth = "Aug"; }
                    if ($moS == 8) { $toolMonth = "Sep"; }
                    if ($moS == 9) { $toolMonth = "Oct"; }
                    if ($moS == 10) { $toolMonth = "Nov"; }
                    if ($moS == 11) { $toolMonth = "Dec"; }
                    $toolDate = $toolMonth + $daS;
                    $dTotal = new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS, 00, 00, 00, 0);
                    $day = 60 * 60 * 72 * 1000;
                    $dteEnd = new Date($dTotal.getTime() + $day);
                    $dteEnd = $dteEnd.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
                    $dteEndSplt = $dteEnd.split("/");
                    $yrE = $dteEndSplt[2];
                    $moE = $dteEndSplt[0] - 1;
                    $daE = $dteEndSplt[1];
                    $toolTip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip">' + $toolDate + ": " + a.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2) + '</div>';
              }
          } 
          dataTable.addRows([ [ $project, null, $toolTip, new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS), new Date($yrE, $moE, $daE) ] ]);
      } 
    
      for(var i = 0; i < countRowB; i++) {
          for(var ii = 0; ii < countColumnB; ii++) {
              if (ii == 0) {
                    $project = b.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
                    $dteStrt = b.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 3);
                    $dteStrtSplt = $dteStrt.split(",");
                    $yrS = $dteStrtSplt[0];
                    $moS = $dteStrtSplt[1] - 1;
                    $daS = $dteStrtSplt[2];
                    if ($moS == 0) { $toolMonth = "Jan"; }
                    if ($moS == 1) { $toolMonth = "Feb"; }
                    if ($moS == 2) { $toolMonth = "Mar"; }
                    if ($moS == 3) { $toolMonth = "Apr"; }
                    if ($moS == 4) { $toolMonth = "May"; }
                    if ($moS == 5) { $toolMonth = "Jun"; }
                    if ($moS == 6) { $toolMonth = "Jul"; }
                    if ($moS == 7) { $toolMonth = "Aug"; }
                    if ($moS == 8) { $toolMonth = "Sep"; }
                    if ($moS == 9) { $toolMonth = "Oct"; }
                    if ($moS == 10) { $toolMonth = "Nov"; }
                    if ($moS == 11) { $toolMonth = "Dec"; }
                    $toolDate = $toolMonth + $daS;
                    $dTotal = new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS, 00, 00, 00, 0);
                    $day = 60 * 60 * 72 * 1000;
                    $dteEnd = new Date($dTotal.getTime() + $day);
                    $dteEnd = $dteEnd.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
                    $dteEndSplt = $dteEnd.split("/");
                    $yrE = $dteEndSplt[2];
                    $moE = $dteEndSplt[0] - 1;
                    $daE = $dteEndSplt[1];
                    $toolTip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip">' + $toolDate + ": " + b.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2) + '</div>';
              }
          } 
          dataTable.addRows([ [ $project, null, $toolTip, new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS), new Date($yrE, $moE, $daE) ] ]);
      } 
        
      for(var i = 0; i < countRowC; i++) {
          for(var ii = 0; ii < countColumnC; ii++) {
              if (ii == 0) {
                    $project = c.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
                    $dteStrt = c.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 3);
                    $dteStrtSplt = $dteStrt.split(",");
                    $yrS = $dteStrtSplt[0];
                    $moS = $dteStrtSplt[1] - 1;
                    $daS = $dteStrtSplt[2];
                    if ($moS == 0) { $toolMonth = "Jan"; }
                    if ($moS == 1) { $toolMonth = "Feb"; }
                    if ($moS == 2) { $toolMonth = "Mar"; }
                    if ($moS == 3) { $toolMonth = "Apr"; }
                    if ($moS == 4) { $toolMonth = "May"; }
                    if ($moS == 5) { $toolMonth = "Jun"; }
                    if ($moS == 6) { $toolMonth = "Jul"; }
                    if ($moS == 7) { $toolMonth = "Aug"; }
                    if ($moS == 8) { $toolMonth = "Sep"; }
                    if ($moS == 9) { $toolMonth = "Oct"; }
                    if ($moS == 10) { $toolMonth = "Nov"; }
                    if ($moS == 11) { $toolMonth = "Dec"; }
                    $toolDate = $toolMonth + $daS;
                    $dTotal = new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS, 00, 00, 00, 0);
                    $day = 60 * 60 * 72 * 1000;
                    $dteEnd = new Date($dTotal.getTime() + $day);
                    $dteEnd = $dteEnd.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
                    $dteEndSplt = $dteEnd.split("/");
                    $yrE = $dteEndSplt[2];
                    $moE = $dteEndSplt[0] - 1;
                    $daE = $dteEndSplt[1];
                    $toolTip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip">' + $toolDate + ": " + c.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2) + '</div>';
              }
          } 
          dataTable.addRows([ [ $project, null, $toolTip, new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS), new Date($yrE, $moE, $daE) ] ]);
      } 
        
      for(var i = 0; i < countRowD; i++) {
          for(var ii = 0; ii < countColumnD; ii++) {
              if (ii == 0) {
                    $project = d.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
                    $dteStrt = d.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 3);
                    $dteStrtSplt = $dteStrt.split(",");
                    $yrS = $dteStrtSplt[0];
                    $moS = $dteStrtSplt[1] - 1;
                    $daS = $dteStrtSplt[2];
                    if ($moS == 0) { $toolMonth = "Jan"; }
                    if ($moS == 1) { $toolMonth = "Feb"; }
                    if ($moS == 2) { $toolMonth = "Mar"; }
                    if ($moS == 3) { $toolMonth = "Apr"; }
                    if ($moS == 4) { $toolMonth = "May"; }
                    if ($moS == 5) { $toolMonth = "Jun"; }
                    if ($moS == 6) { $toolMonth = "Jul"; }
                    if ($moS == 7) { $toolMonth = "Aug"; }
                    if ($moS == 8) { $toolMonth = "Sep"; }
                    if ($moS == 9) { $toolMonth = "Oct"; }
                    if ($moS == 10) { $toolMonth = "Nov"; }
                    if ($moS == 11) { $toolMonth = "Dec"; }
                    $toolDate = $toolMonth + $daS;
                    $dTotal = new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS, 00, 00, 00, 0);
                    $day = 60 * 60 * 72 * 1000;
                    $dteEnd = new Date($dTotal.getTime() + $day);
                    $dteEnd = $dteEnd.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
                    $dteEndSplt = $dteEnd.split("/");
                    $yrE = $dteEndSplt[2];
                    $moE = $dteEndSplt[0] - 1;
                    $daE = $dteEndSplt[1];
                    $toolTip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip">' + $toolDate + ": " + d.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2) + '</div>';
              }
          } 
          dataTable.addRows([ [ $project, null, $toolTip, new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS), new Date($yrE, $moE, $daE) ] ]);
      }
        
      for(var i = 0; i < countRowE; i++) {
          for(var ii = 0; ii < countColumnE; ii++) {
              if (ii == 0) {
                    $project = e.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
                    $dteStrt = e.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 3);
                    $dteStrtSplt = $dteStrt.split(",");
                    $yrS = $dteStrtSplt[0];
                    $moS = $dteStrtSplt[1] - 1;
                    $daS = $dteStrtSplt[2];
                    if ($moS == 0) { $toolMonth = "Jan"; }
                    if ($moS == 1) { $toolMonth = "Feb"; }
                    if ($moS == 2) { $toolMonth = "Mar"; }
                    if ($moS == 3) { $toolMonth = "Apr"; }
                    if ($moS == 4) { $toolMonth = "May"; }
                    if ($moS == 5) { $toolMonth = "Jun"; }
                    if ($moS == 6) { $toolMonth = "Jul"; }
                    if ($moS == 7) { $toolMonth = "Aug"; }
                    if ($moS == 8) { $toolMonth = "Sep"; }
                    if ($moS == 9) { $toolMonth = "Oct"; }
                    if ($moS == 10) { $toolMonth = "Nov"; }
                    if ($moS == 11) { $toolMonth = "Dec"; }
                    $toolDate = $toolMonth + $daS;
                    $dTotal = new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS, 00, 00, 00, 0);
                    $day = 60 * 60 * 72 * 1000;
                    $dteEnd = new Date($dTotal.getTime() + $day);
                    $dteEnd = $dteEnd.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
                    $dteEndSplt = $dteEnd.split("/");
                    $yrE = $dteEndSplt[2];
                    $moE = $dteEndSplt[0] - 1;
                    $daE = $dteEndSplt[1];
                    $toolTip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip">' + $toolDate + ": " + e.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2) + '</div>';
              }
          } 
          dataTable.addRows([ [ $project, null, $toolTip, new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS), new Date($yrE, $moE, $daE) ] ]);
      }
        
      for(var i = 0; i < countRowF; i++) {
          for(var ii = 0; ii < countColumnF; ii++) {
              if (ii == 0) {
                    $project = f.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
                    $dteStrt = f.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 3);
                    $dteStrtSplt = $dteStrt.split(",");
                    $yrS = $dteStrtSplt[0];
                    $moS = $dteStrtSplt[1] - 1;
                    $daS = $dteStrtSplt[2];
                    if ($moS == 0) { $toolMonth = "Jan"; }
                    if ($moS == 1) { $toolMonth = "Feb"; }
                    if ($moS == 2) { $toolMonth = "Mar"; }
                    if ($moS == 3) { $toolMonth = "Apr"; }
                    if ($moS == 4) { $toolMonth = "May"; }
                    if ($moS == 5) { $toolMonth = "Jun"; }
                    if ($moS == 6) { $toolMonth = "Jul"; }
                    if ($moS == 7) { $toolMonth = "Aug"; }
                    if ($moS == 8) { $toolMonth = "Sep"; }
                    if ($moS == 9) { $toolMonth = "Oct"; }
                    if ($moS == 10) { $toolMonth = "Nov"; }
                    if ($moS == 11) { $toolMonth = "Dec"; }
                    $toolDate = $toolMonth + $daS;
                    $dTotal = new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS, 00, 00, 00, 0);
                    $day = 60 * 60 * 72 * 1000;
                    $dteEnd = new Date($dTotal.getTime() + $day);
                    $dteEnd = $dteEnd.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
                    $dteEndSplt = $dteEnd.split("/");
                    $yrE = $dteEndSplt[2];
                    $moE = $dteEndSplt[0] - 1;
                    $daE = $dteEndSplt[1];
                    $toolTip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip">' + $toolDate + ": " + f.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2) + '</div>';
              }
          } 
          dataTable.addRows([ [ $project, null, $toolTip, new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS), new Date($yrE, $moE, $daE) ] ]);
      }
        
      for(var i = 0; i < countRowG; i++) {
          for(var ii = 0; ii < countColumnG; ii++) {
              if (ii == 0) {
                    $project = g.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
                    $dteStrt = g.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 3);
                    $dteStrtSplt = $dteStrt.split(",");
                    $yrS = $dteStrtSplt[0];
                    $moS = $dteStrtSplt[1] - 1;
                    $daS = $dteStrtSplt[2];
                    if ($moS == 0) { $toolMonth = "Jan"; }
                    if ($moS == 1) { $toolMonth = "Feb"; }
                    if ($moS == 2) { $toolMonth = "Mar"; }
                    if ($moS == 3) { $toolMonth = "Apr"; }
                    if ($moS == 4) { $toolMonth = "May"; }
                    if ($moS == 5) { $toolMonth = "Jun"; }
                    if ($moS == 6) { $toolMonth = "Jul"; }
                    if ($moS == 7) { $toolMonth = "Aug"; }
                    if ($moS == 8) { $toolMonth = "Sep"; }
                    if ($moS == 9) { $toolMonth = "Oct"; }
                    if ($moS == 10) { $toolMonth = "Nov"; }
                    if ($moS == 11) { $toolMonth = "Dec"; }
                    $toolDate = $toolMonth + $daS;
                    $dTotal = new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS, 00, 00, 00, 0);
                    $day = 60 * 60 * 72 * 1000;
                    $dteEnd = new Date($dTotal.getTime() + $day);
                    $dteEnd = $dteEnd.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
                    $dteEndSplt = $dteEnd.split("/");
                    $yrE = $dteEndSplt[2];
                    $moE = $dteEndSplt[0] - 1;
                    $daE = $dteEndSplt[1];
                    $toolTip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip">' + $toolDate + ": " + g.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2) + '</div>';
              }
          } 
          dataTable.addRows([ [ $project, null, $toolTip, new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS), new Date($yrE, $moE, $daE) ] ]);
      }
        
      for(var i = 0; i < countRowH; i++) {
          for(var ii = 0; ii < countColumnH; ii++) {
              if (ii == 0) {
                    $project = h.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
                    $dteStrt = h.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 3);
                    $dteStrtSplt = $dteStrt.split(",");
                    $yrS = $dteStrtSplt[0];
                    $moS = $dteStrtSplt[1] - 1;
                    $daS = $dteStrtSplt[2];
                    if ($moS == 0) { $toolMonth = "Jan"; }
                    if ($moS == 1) { $toolMonth = "Feb"; }
                    if ($moS == 2) { $toolMonth = "Mar"; }
                    if ($moS == 3) { $toolMonth = "Apr"; }
                    if ($moS == 4) { $toolMonth = "May"; }
                    if ($moS == 5) { $toolMonth = "Jun"; }
                    if ($moS == 6) { $toolMonth = "Jul"; }
                    if ($moS == 7) { $toolMonth = "Aug"; }
                    if ($moS == 8) { $toolMonth = "Sep"; }
                    if ($moS == 9) { $toolMonth = "Oct"; }
                    if ($moS == 10) { $toolMonth = "Nov"; }
                    if ($moS == 11) { $toolMonth = "Dec"; }
                    $toolDate = $toolMonth + $daS;
                    $dTotal = new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS, 00, 00, 00, 0);
                    $day = 60 * 60 * 72 * 1000;
                    $dteEnd = new Date($dTotal.getTime() + $day);
                    $dteEnd = $dteEnd.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
                    $dteEndSplt = $dteEnd.split("/");
                    $yrE = $dteEndSplt[2];
                    $moE = $dteEndSplt[0] - 1;
                    $daE = $dteEndSplt[1];
                    $toolTip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip">' + $toolDate + ": " + h.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2) + '</div>';
              }
          } 
          dataTable.addRows([ [ $project, null, $toolTip, new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS), new Date($yrE, $moE, $daE) ] ]);
      }
        
    
        
     chart.draw(dataTable, {
          tooltip: {
            isHtml: true
          }
        });
    }
    
    </script>
          
        <style>
            .chart {
              width: 95%; 
              min-height: 900px;
              margin-left: 2.5%;
            }
            
            .ggl-tooltip {
              border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
              font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
              padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
            font-weight: bold;
            }
            
            div#chart_div path {
               stroke:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) !important;
            }
        </style>
          
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
        <div id="point"  class="chart"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: could be a number of things, can you share the code that calls the above function? are you waiting for google's load callback to finish? are you checking for errors in the query's response?

Comment: I updated my question above with the full code. How do I know if google's load callback has finished?

Comment: first, you're using the load statement from the old version of google charts. only need one load statement, please see --> [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code)...

Comment: I updated to the new load statement and updated my code above. Not much difference in performance yet.

Comment: the `query.send` method runs asynchronously, which means you don't know when its going to finish, thus the callback function. just because you send H last, doesn't mean it will be the last to finish. you need a way to confirm all queries have finished before continuing...